# jQuery Sortable - no dragging past last list item

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have an unsorted list (`UL`) that contains sortable list items (`LI`), except for the last list item. I need the last item to stay at the end of the list:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Last item</li><!-- Should always be the last item -->
</ul>
```

I'm using [jQuery Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable) for sorting the list items.

Does anyone know a good way to prevent list items from being dragged past the last list item?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can pass a selector that excludes the last item in the [items](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-items) option:

```
$("ul").sortable({
    items: "li:not(:last-child)"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You better use `cancel` property

http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-cancel

```
$("ul").sortable({
        items: 'li',
        cancel: 'li:last-child'
});
```

or add class to last `li` element and then:

```
$("ul").sortable({
        items: 'li',
        cancel: '.last-el-class'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Today you can leave it to **CSS** using **content** and **custom data**:

**HTML**:

```
<ul data-lastitem="Last item">
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**:

```
ul:after {
  content: attr(data-lastitem)
}
li, ul:after {
  border: 0.15em solid #ccc;
  margin: 0.8em 0;
  padding: 0.8em;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #FFF;
  display:block
}
```

Then the **Javascript** would be just so:

```
$("ul").sortable();
```

See it's working in the [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/nocoku/1)